# Android - NumberPicker doesn't show + and - buttons

Tags: android, time

I wanna take an hour as input from user using a Number Picker, but it doesn't show the + and - buttons, it's just a values wheel

Comment: I strongly believe that this has been asked before, do some more Google-ing

Comment: I Googled but I really didn't know how to ask it. You know, English is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways that you can do this. I would take that string and then parse it down to see what you find then handle the string accordingly. Say you have an edit text field and it returns the string `HourText`. The way I would handle this, would be to use a [number picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html), set an upper and lower limit. Then you are returned a type int. From that you can use >=20 or >=50. In my mind using a numberPicker, and then handling the value accordingly sounds easier.

Comment: I should use a TextListener, in the beforeChange (or whatever) method check if the hour is ok and save it as a string. And in the afterChange method, in case that the string typed is not alright, change the content of the EditText back to the saved string, right? Is this implementation correct?

Comment: If you use a number picker, you don't have to worry about much, it sets an upper bound, and a lower bound. When you go to retrieve the 'ints' from the number picker, you just do a simple if(numb1>20){now it won't matter if they hit a 21, 22,23,24, now you can just set it to a default value above 20.} The same process can be used for minutes. I don't know if this answered your question, as I don't have a clear understanding of the scope of project.

Comment: Oh! When I first read your answer, I was in a hurry. I didn't know that Android implemented that kind of object. Even better. Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem is that the NumberPicker doesn't have the + and - buttons :/ I heard it was the old version and you can still get it though

Comment: I mean [numberpickers](http://codejeff.com/?p=42) have built in + and -, not knowing the whole project makes it hard for me not knowing the limitations

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really couldn't find anything on the Internet. Here are some screenshots with the code and running app.
[link](http://postimg.org/image/qs60a73nd/)
[link](http://postimg.org/image/v2ko5s8qh/)
[link](http://postimg.org/image/polvy8j09/)

Comment: What api version are you using, that will make a small amount of difference. Also, please edit your question to show code, and don't add image links to code.

Comment: I need 20 reputation points to post the images, sorry. And I'm a little confused with SDK and API, where can I find the API? I tried different Android versions.